# Node.js: if-modified-since date is always different than mtime stat file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have no idea why the date parsed from request header `if-modified-since` is always different than pate parsed from `mtime` in node stat function even when file was not modified.

the code i have for modification conditions is like this:

```
fs.stat(file.dir, function(err, stats){
    if(err){
        $.status("500");
        $.end();

        console.error(err);
    }

    else{
        /*
         * Check if file was modified, send 304 if not
         */
        if(!$.header("if-modified-since")){
            $.header("Last-Modified", new Date(stats.mtime).toUTCString());
            sendFile(file, $);
        }

        else{
            var lastModified = new Date($.header("if-modified-since"));
            var modified = new Date(stats.mtime);

            console.log($.url.pathname, lastModified.getTime(), modified.getTime());

            if(modified.getTime() == lastModified.getTime()){
                $.status("304");
                $.end();
            }

            else{
                $.header("Last-Modified", new Date(stats.mtime).toUTCString());
                sendFile(file, $);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

the log in the code have this results:

```
// On non-modified file request
/style.css 1478834712000 1478834712057

// On modified file request
/style.css 1478834712000 1478834851656

// On non-modified file request after modified file request
/style.css 1478834851000 1478834851656
```

does this have something to do with `node.js` version?, currently i am using `v6.9.1` on `Ubuntu 16.04 x64 Desktop`

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason why the values were always different, turns out the headers `last-modified` and `if-modified-since` are dates of `UTC` format while the date from file `stat.mtime` is a date of `ISO 8901` format, this means that when parsed `ISO 8901` has more specific time than `UTC` which explains why the last 3 digits from `getTime()` are always different, making the logic condition to always fail.

So to fix this, i made a function to compare both dates from method `getTime()` but the last 3 digits are ignored due to `UTC` that does not provide these values, the function looks like this:

```
var isEqualTime = function(time1, time2){
    var time1 = new Date(time1)
        .getTime()
        .toString()
        .slice(0, -3);

    var time2 = new Date(time2)
        .getTime()
        .toString()
        .slice(0, -3);

    return time1 == time2;
}
```

so in the code that needs this results is now modified to be like this:

```
var lastModified = $.header("if-modified-since");
var modified = file.stats.mtime;

// send file if "if-modified-since" header is undefined
// if defined then compare if file is modified
if(!lastModified || !helper.isEqualTime(lastModified, modified)){
    sendFile($, file);
}

// send 304 if file was not modified
else{
    $.status("304");
    $.end();
}
```

`file` variable object now contains the stats of the file which in function `sendFile()` sends the header `last-modified`